# Setting the x locations of elements (from data field in the data) after appending them in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have the following code, where I read a file, and then use `d3.map` to get the unique `user_id` values to create column labels of a heat map:

```
d3.tsv("data_heatmap.tsv", function(d) {
    console.log(d.user_id);
    return {                
        col : +d.u_id,
        row : +d.d_id,
        value : +d.count,
        user_id: +d.user_id,
    };

    var colLabels = svg.append("g").selectAll(".colLabelg")
                   .data(d3.map(data, function(d) {return d.user_id;}.keys())
                   .enter().append("text")
                   .text(function(d) {return d;}
    )
}
```

This code works fine, but I need to use the `col` variable to change the positions of the `.colLabelg` elements created. I tried the following but it does not work:

```
    var colLabels = svg.append("g").selectAll(".colLabelg")
                   .data(d3.map(data, function(d) {return d.user_id;}.keys())
                   .enter().append("text")
                   .text(function(d) {return d;}
    ).data(d3.map(data, function(d){return d.u_id;}).keys())
     .enter().attr("x", 0).attr("y", function(d) {
                return d * cellSize; 
    })
```

But, it gives an error:

[image]

What would be the solution to this problem?

Comment: That will never work: you are re-binding the data and calling `enter()` again in an enter selection. If you want to use unique `user_id`s together with other values, you have to create a new array which keeps all the properties of the objects.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado after I use `d3.map` to get the unique `user_id` values, I do not know how I can get the `col` values. Could you please guide me a little here? You meant I need to create an array ahead of time separately?.

Comment: Well, I can't help you because I don't know how `col` correlates with `user_id`. That's an important information for removing duplicated obkects (without using map).